# Simulink callback problem

Tags: matlab, callback, simulink

Hey, I have a maybe very simple problem using the PreLoadFcn in my model.

I want my model to load a m-file before starting the simulation (this is what the preloadfcn is for, i think).

So I added in file -> model properties -> callbacks -> PreLoadFcn the line

```
run('./init.m')
```

In this file there are several variables set. My Model refers to those variables and throws the exception, that it can't find them when I simply click on "Start simulation". This indicates me, that the callback isn't doing what it should be doing...

The file 'init.m' is in the same directory like the simulation file.

Even trying to add the directory to the matlab PATH didn't take any effect.

greets poeschlorn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work simply to run "init" at the MATLAB command prompt prior to running the model? If so, you should probably replace the callback with simply

```
init
```

which will run the script "init.m".

Comment: Typing 'init' into matlab comand line works, but not on the callback

Comment: I found it. I had to declare a function within this m-file :)

Comment: @poeschlorn You mean having just run('./init.m') in the callback does not work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Callback tracing to see what callbacks are being called during the process of loading and simulating your model.  See the [documentation on callbacks](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f4-122589.html) for more info.

Also, is init a script or a function? It should be a script, or it should use evalin('base') to put the vars in the base workspace.  You can also try putting a breakpoint in init.m to make sure it doesn't get hit.

Comment: hi, init is a script which is exacly named "init.m". It contains no further functions within. It just initialises some variables in my workspace. Regarding to your first prompt I used "StartFcn" instead (executing the script before simulation starts), but it didn't take any effect

Comment: Strange, I don't know exactly why this isn't working.  I've used callbacks many times in models to do exactly what you're doing, and they always work.  One other thing to try is to paste the contents of init.m directly into the callback.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem. Now it has been solved. 
the solution was quit simple. 
after defining the function in the PreLoadFcn*
you just need to save the simulink file, and restart it. 
surely it will work.

greetings, 
Harry